# module.exports not returning result in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function in a latestVideo.js file:

```
function getLatestVideo() {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      let reqBody = body.toString();
      reqBody = JSON.parse(reqBody);

      const latestVideoID = reqBody.items['0'].id.videoId;
      return videoLink + latestVideoID;
    }
  });

}
module.exports.getLatestVideo = getLatestVideo;
```

Then in another file I want to use the output of the function like:

```
const latestVideo = require('./latestVideo');

console.log(latestVideo.getLatestVideo)
```

But it does not execute the function. It just says `[Function: getLatestVideo]` in my console. But I return a value right, so why is the function not executing?

Comment: you did not return anything in your `getLatestVideo()` function and also  you are using `request` in an undocumented way, learn what a callback is and get the result of the `request` function accordingly

Comment: I'm learning Node.js, but thanks, super helpfull comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:  `latestVideo.getLatestVideo()`

You get undefined because you doesnt return anything. You use `return` in an callback function. Here is a solution for your problem:

```
async function getLatestVideo() {
   return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      request(url, function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            let reqBody = body.toString();
            reqBody = JSON.parse(reqBody);
            const latestVideoID = reqBody.items['0'].id.videoId;
            resolve(videoLink + latestVideoID);
         }
     });
   })
}
```

Comment: do you need to export just 1 function or more?

Comment: I am getting not the same result btw, I am getting `undefined` then

Comment: ok it works. Next step is to fix your function because it has some issues

Answer (score 0):

You're not running the function just returning the function

make `latestVideo.getLatestVideo` to `latestVideo.getLatestVideo()`

[image]

Comment: I get `undefined` then

Comment: It's working it's your function returning `undefined` there is most likely a problem with the function